# Memory issue while running WODM (JRULES)

Tags: out-of-memory, ilog, jrules, ibm-odm

I'm creating a ruleApp and deploying it into the Rule Execution server. While executing the rules it starts throwing the OutOfMemory error.

```
000000bd execution     E   The interaction ruleEngine.execute has failed.
                                 com.ibm.rules.res.xu.internal.LocalizedResourceException: GBRXU0001E: The interaction ruleEngine.execute has failed.
        at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.client.internal.jca.XUInteraction.execute(XUInteraction.java:302)
        at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.client.internal.XUSession.executeOperation(XUSession.java:171)
        at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.client.internal.XURuleEngineSession.execute(XURuleEngineSession.java:603)
        at ilog.rules.res.session.impl.IlrStatefulSessionBase.execute(IlrStatefulSessionBase.java:725)
        at ilog.rules.res.session.impl.IlrStatefulSessionBase.execute(IlrStatefulSessionBase.java:714)
        at ilog.rules.res.session.impl.IlrStatefulSessionBase.execute(IlrStatefulSessionBase.java:625)
        at ilog.rules.res.session.impl.IlrStatefulSessionBase.execute(IlrStatefulSessionBase.java:269)
        at ilog.rules.res.session.impl.IlrStatefulSessionBase.execute(IlrStatefulSessionBase.java:241)
        at ilog.rules.res.session.impl.IlrStatelessSessionBase.execute(IlrStatelessSessionBase.java:63)
        at com.bnsf.rules.services.framework.RuleExecutioner.invokeRuleService(RuTioner.java:50)
        at com.bnsf.rules.services.framework.RuleExecutioner.invokeSimpleRuleService(RuTioner.java:24)
        at com.bnsf.rules.services.MiscBillingRuleService.execBatch(Miservice.java:222)
        at com.bnsf.rules.services.MiscBillingRuleService.performTask(MisService.java:158)
        at com.bnsf.rules.services.MiscBillingRuleService.execute(MisService.java:88)
        at com.bnsf.rules.services.MiscBillingRuleServiceThread.run(MisThread.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.ensureCapacityImpl(StringBuffer.java:338)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:204)
        at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:113)
        at java.io.StringWriter.append(StringWriter.java:155)
        at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.engine.de.internal.DEManager.note(DEManager.java:554)
        at com.ibm.rules.engine.runtime.impl.EngineObserverManager.note(EngineObserverManager.java:84)
        at com.ibm.rules.engine.rete.runtime.AbstractReteEngine.note(AbstractReteEngine.java:686)
       at com.ibm.rules.generated.EngineDataClass.ilog_rules_brl_System_printMessage_java_lang_String(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.rules.generated.ruleflow.Service$0020Definition.IntermediateDefnFlow$003eIntermediate$0020Event$0020Definition.BodyExecEnv.executeIntermediate$0020Events$0020For$0020Intra$002dplant$0020Switch$002dEndEventBody3(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.rules.generated.ruleflow.Service$0020Definition.IntermediateDefnFlow$003eIntermediate$0020Event$0020Definition.BodyExecEnv.executeB
```

I'm using print statement in each of the rules, so does the error mean the print statement is filling up the heap memory of my application. Also, the error message shows a particular package in the ruleset. Removing the print statement from that package alone will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the Java heap is too small to run your app, but the typical cause of this error is an infinite loop in the rules. You (or an admin) can verify that the WebSphere config options specify a reasonable heap size.

Another possibility is that some other app is using all the heap space -- my current organization has to re-start their dev server every week to restore the heap space from a memory leak they have not yet found. In this case, the rules execute just fine, but when viewing a (large) decision trace in the Decision Warehouse in RES I will sometimes get an out of heap space error.